# Image won't fit in scale to fill mode in image view

Tags: ios, objective-c, image

It's a really simple task but somehow it just did not work for me.
This is what I did:

1. In storyboard, add an image view to my controller, pin each side to superview, with 0 distance.
2. Set the image of the image view to be a PNG image which is 646 x 1140.
3. Set the mode to scale to fill

Then in my simulator, the view controller looks like this:

[image: screenshot of the bug]

As the screenshot shows, there are white spaces around the image.

I can confirm the image itself does not have white spaces around it, and the image view pins well to the four sides of its superview.
So why does it look like this? Did I miss anything?

Comment: Check your image. I think ur image is like this

Comment: otherwise direct set the image frame size (0, 0, 320, 568)

Comment: Set ContentMode to AspectFit and see what happens

Comment: @SRNayak I did mention that I can confirm my image does not have white spaces around it

Comment: @Debanjan I tried every option for ContentMode in Interface Builder,  for those options that should fill, they all have white spaces.

Comment: may be your image transparent little bit from left ,once try to to change the veiw's color if the white will also change then it will confirmed.

Comment: @guru Yes it is! I should've noticed that! Sorry that I have wasted you guys' time..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be your image transparent little bit from left ,once try to to change the veiw's color if the white will also change then it will confirm.

Answer (score 2):

set your image as

```
yourimage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

some other variation using as per `apple documentation`

```
 typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIViewContentMode) {
UIViewContentModeScaleToFill,
UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit,      // contents scaled to fit with fixed aspect. remainder is transparent
UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill,     // contents scaled to fill with fixed aspect. some portion of content may be clipped.
UIViewContentModeRedraw,              // redraw on bounds change (calls -setNeedsDisplay)
UIViewContentModeCenter,              // contents remain same size. positioned adjusted.
UIViewContentModeTop,
UIViewContentModeBottom,
UIViewContentModeLeft,
UIViewContentModeRight,
UIViewContentModeTopLeft,
UIViewContentModeTopRight,
UIViewContentModeBottomLeft,
UIViewContentModeBottomRight,
};
```